# Redirection after login in Spring Authentication (Environment problem, Tomcat vs Jetty)

Tags: spring, tomcat, jetty

The app I am maintaining has a custom Single Sign On implementation.
After receiving a valid token (which it provided earlier and stored to db), 
the app executes a CustomAuthenticationFilter successfully.

The app works fine at "Jetty" on Eclipse. After a valid url request sent, the app successfully opens the welcome page which is just after login page.

Url request:
http://99.99.99.99:8090/MyApp/j_spring_security_check?tokenId=19d79b76-0d1e-4327-871b-0e8792e03be2

But when deploy it to a "tomcat", do a valid url request, instead of opening welcome page, it stucks at login page (below)

http://99.99.99.99:8090/MyApp/login.xhtml;jsessionid=3B8C865260E86F3609F75199A23A1120

The application deployed to both, ports purely the same. No exception in logs. Even I can read successful login logs in tomcat. I can't figure out why it behaves different?

Comment: Maybe it's because you are using a URL based session behavior? (the `;jsessionid=` piece).  What does your session configuration look like in your `WEB-INF/web.xml`?

Comment: Thanks Joakim. I suspect something browser specific. Chrome, Firefox and Internet explorer behaved differently, where firefox directed to login page, chrome asked a username/password via pop-up. But Internet explorer did what I try to achieve. Directed to welcome page just after login. So for now I will proceed with explorer where I am left very tight time for release. But any suggestions are welcome for improvements and knowledge gathering. Thank you

Comment: You might want to consider NOT USING the `jsessionid=` in the URL, its considered a security vulnerability (even if using SSL/TLS).

Comment: Thank you for the warning. I will check that.